# Apple Pay without Stripe iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, stripe-payments, applepay

I've been using Stripe iOS SDK for a while now and everything is clear regarding the implementation. Since our app is going to support App Clips on iOS 14, we are reducing the binary size and therefore decided to remove Stripe iOS SDK as well.

So my question here is if I can somehow send payment requests via the API and omitting the Stripe SDK altogether?

*p.s.: It looks like I need to implement the [/tokens](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card) endpoint passing the card data. Is there any example of the request to be made?*

Comment: It's possible but there isn't official documentation for it because it's a very advanced integration that most people wouldn't do. You'd need to implement the Apple Pay [SDK calls](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/) yourself, and then make a request to Stripe's API with the resulting PKPayment, there are some [undocumented parameters to /v1/tokens.](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/7e74d50f22d93a3132433284a10522db64bf4b31/Stripe/STPAPIClient%2BApplePay.m#L121-L150)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was referring to. I still hope there are some examples where all params are explained.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve this situation and here is the solution if anyone is interested. Here are the steps to make this happen:

1. Prepare a request model

```swift
import Foundation
import PassKit

struct StripeTokenRequest: Encodable {
  let pkToken: String
  let card: Card
  let pkTokenInstrumentName: String?
  let pkTokenPaymentNetwork: String?
  let pkTokenTransactionId: String?
  
  init?(payment: PKPayment) {
    guard let paymentString = String(data: payment.token.paymentData, encoding: .utf8) else { return nil }
    pkToken = paymentString
    card = .init(contact: payment.billingContact)
    pkTokenInstrumentName = payment.token.paymentMethod.displayName
    pkTokenPaymentNetwork = payment.token.paymentMethod.network.map { $0.rawValue }
    pkTokenTransactionId = payment.token.transactionIdentifier
  }
}

extension StripeTokenRequest {
  struct Card: Encodable {
    let name: String?
    let addressLine1: String?
    let addressCity: String?
    let addressState: String?
    let addressZip: String?
    let addressCountry: String?
    
    init(contact: PKContact?) {
      name = contact?.name.map { PersonNameComponentsFormatter.localizedString(from: $0, style: .default, options: []) }
      addressLine1 = contact?.postalAddress?.street
      addressCity = contact?.postalAddress?.city
      addressState = contact?.postalAddress?.state
      addressZip = contact?.postalAddress?.postalCode
      addressCountry = contact?.postalAddress?.isoCountryCode.uppercased()
    }
  }
}
```

2. Use `JSONEncoder` and set `keyEncodingStrategy` to `.convertToSnakeCase`.
3. Create a POST request against `https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens` endpoint where you need to url encode parameters. If you are using Alamofire, you need to set encoding to `URLEncoding.default`.
4. Parse response. I use `JSONDecoder` with the following model:

```swift
import Foundation

struct StripeTokenResponse: Decodable {
  let id: String
}
```

5. Create a payment
   `StripeTokenResponse.id` is the thing you need to pass to the backend where the payment will be processed. This is the same step as you'll do when using the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Strip checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment), it allows you to present a payment page in web format without any Stripe SDK on the client side.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me. We have Apple Pay and I don't want to bring another step for the user in order to pay for the service.

Comment: `Stripe checkout` supports apple pay natively. But ya, if it's about UX then you may need to implement the token thing mentioned by @karllekko by yourself.